# pass data from button onclick to ajax code

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a problem in Ajax.

My JS File:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).ajaxStart(function() {
    $("#wait").css("display", "block");
  });
  $(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
    $("#wait").css("display", "none");
  });
  $("button").click(function() {
    $.post("ajax", {
        name: "Donald Duck",
        _token: "{!! csrf_token() !!}",
        city: "Duckburg"
      },
      function(data, status) {
        alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
      });
  });
});
```

my html code:

```html
<div id="wait" style="display:none;width:69px;height:89px;border:1px solid black;position:absolute;top:50%;left:50%;padding:2px;">
  <img src='demo_wait.gif' width="64" height="64" />
  <br>Loading..</div>

<button>Start</button>
```

And it works fine , I need passing a value from button code to Javascript, which I then use for the Post URL.

I changed the js file to:

```js
function MyJS(str) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).ajaxStart(function() {
      $("#wait").css("display", "block");
    });
    $(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
      $("#wait").css("display", "none");
    });
    $("button").click(function() {
      $.post("ajax" + str, {
          name: "Donald Duck",
          _token: "{!! csrf_token() !!}",
          city: "Duckburg"
        },
        function(data, status) {
          alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
        });
    });
  });
}
```

and my new html code is:

```
  <div id="wait" style="display:none;width:69px;height:89px;border:1px solid black;position:absolute;top:50%;left:50%;padding:2px;"><img src='demo_wait.gif' width="64" height="64" /><br>Loading..</div>
<button onclick="MyJS('9');">Start</button>
```

After the changes, the code seems to stop working.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `data-*` prefixed custom attributes to store arbitrary information with the element which can be used later.

```
<button data-key="9">Start</button>
```

Then using your existing click handler, You can use [`Element.dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) property to access the data. Using jQuery the same result can be achieved using [`.data('key')`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) method.

```
$("button").click(function() {
    var str = this.dataset.key; //$(this).data('key')
});
```

Note: And get rid of inline-click handler.

Comment: A button without `type="button"` is a submit in many browsers

Answer (score 0):

- Do not put your document.ready and your ajaxStart code in a function
- add `type="button"` to not submit the page to itself in several browsers
- use the data attribute or value to pass the string to your server:

Like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).ajaxStart(function() {
    $("#wait").css("display", "block");
  });
  $(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
    $("#wait").css("display", "none");
  });
  $("button").click(function() {
    $.post("ajax", {
        id:$(this).data("id"),
        name: "Donald Duck",
        _token: "{!! csrf_token() !!}",
        city: "Duckburg"
      },
      function(data, status) {
        alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
      });
  });
});
```

using

```
<button type="button" data-id="9">Start</button>
```

or use

```
$(this).val();
```

with

```
<button type="button" value="9">Start</button>
```